# How can I check, using Java, that a given file path is under (any number of levels deep) a given directory path

Tags: java, file, directory

Given two strings - one representing a directory path and the other representing a file path - what is the most efficient way to check whether the file exists under (it could be any levels deep) the given directory.

I started by turning both into `File` objects, and comparing their canonical paths

```
// null checks etc. omitted for brevity
File file = new File(filePath);
String fileCanonicalPath = file.getCanonicalPath();

File dir = new File(dirPath);
String dirCanonicalPath = dir.getCanonicalPath();

return fileCanonicalPath.startsWith(dirCanonicalPath);
```

But I am not convinced this is actually the most accurate way to do it - I would like to rely on what the system considers rather than comparing strings.

I then tried with converting both to `File` objects and then recursively calling the `getParentFile()` on the file, and comparing each one with the directory (using `equals(...)`), until I get the directory or no further parent (`getParent()` returns `null`).

But this seems rather inefficient.

Is there a better way - more efficient and more objectively correct - to do this?

Comment: Please have a look at the java NIO2 API that's been around since Java 7. Especially `Path` or more specifically [`Path.startsWith(Path)​`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#startsWith(java.nio.file.Path)). You don't need to handle strings at all.

Comment: It would be nice if you could edit some example dir-paths and file-paths into the question, because there's still multiple ways to interpret it. I mean, we don't know you, so your attempted solution of comparing the beginning of both paths might not always solve the problem (apart form being slightly crude).

Answer (score 0):

There is a Topic in the Book : Java the complete reference guide (Twelfth edition) in (EXPLORING NIO) season which is "Use walkFileTree() to List a Directory Tree" which explain the java solution to list and do what ever you want with a Directory Tree.

Try to read about walkFileTree() method of java, it will simply solve your problem.
feel free to ask any question you need to know.